# Matlab just says there is an error, but I don't see one. How do I know more about the error

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors

Error in GetSteamZoneParameters (line 7) [ tcD ] = FindtcD( fhv );

I do not get any more description.

The GetSteamZoneParameters function works fine when I call it through the command window. But when I call this function through SAGD.m I get the error.

This code is a part of a simulator for steam injection in oil fields.

```
enter code here
function [ Cw, fhv, Mw, Mo, Mr, s,tD , tcD, WOR, OSR ] = SAGD(fPD, qo,length1, cumTime, cum_oil_tot,cum_wat_tot, cum_steam_tot, cycle, Ts,Ti, Xinj, API, Swi, phi, alpha,... 
                                                                reservoirThickness, Ms, Qi, rl, soakTime, pi, absolutePerm, convFactor,g, Pwf,... 
                                                                Sorw, WIP, rinj, injTime, qwcum, qw, timeStep, prodTime )
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

cum_wat(cycle) = 0.0;
cum_oil(cycle) = 0.0;

if(cycle>1) 
Qi(cycle) = Qi(cycle) + Q(cycle-1);
end
%Start cycle calculations
time=0.0;
while time <= injTime(cycle)+soakTime(cycle)+prodTime(cycle)


    if time <= injTime(cycle) 
    cum_steam_tot = cum_steam_tot + 5.615*rinj(cycle)*timeStep;
    Tavg = Ts;
    end

    if(time == 0.0) 
    [ ~, fhv, ~, ~, ~, ~, ~] = GetVolumetricHeatCapacities( Ts,Ti,Tavg, Xinj, API, Swi, phi, alpha, time, reservoirThickness, Ms);
    [ tcD ] = FindtcD( fhv );
    end

[Cw, fhv, Mw, Mo, Mr, s, tD]  = GetVolumetricHeatCapacities( Ts,Ti,Tavg, Xinj, API, Swi, phi, alpha, time, reservoirThickness, Ms);
[Qi, angleOfInclination, steamZoneRadius, steamZoneVolume ] = GetSteamZoneParameters( Qi,fhv, tD, cycle, rinj, Xinj, time, injTime, Tavg, Ti, Mr, Ts, reservoirThickness, length1);
[ fVD, fHD ] = GetfVDfHD( time, injTime, cycle, alpha, reservoirThickness, steamZoneRadius );
[ fPD] = GetfPD( fPD, Qi, Mo,Mw, cycle, steamZoneVolume,steamZoneRadius, Mr, length1, rl ,Ts, Ti, soakTime, pi, alpha , Tavg, absolutePerm, convFactor, API,reservoirThickness,g, angleOfInclination, Pwf,Sorw, WIP, rinj, injTime, cum_wat, qwcum, qw, timeStep, Swi );
[ Tavg ] = GetTemperatures( cycle, time, Ts, injTime, timeStep, soakTime, Ti, fHD, fVD,fPD);

    if time > injTime(cycle) + soakTime(cycle) 
    [ qo ] = GetInstantaneousOilRate( absolutePerm, convFactor, API,reservoirThickness,g, Tavg, angleOfInclination, pi, Pwf,Sorw, WIP, cycle, rinj, injTime, cum_wat, qwcum, qw, timeStep, Swi );
    [ qw ] = GetInstantaneousWaterRate( WIP ,cycle ,Tavg, Sorw, angleOfInclination, rinj, injTime, cum_wat, qwcum, pi, timeStep, Swi, Pwf, g, reservoirThickness, convFactor, absolutePerm, qw, krw );
    cum_oil_tot = cum_oil_tot + qo;
    cum_wat_tot = cum_wat_tot + qw;
    cum_oil(cycle) = cum_oil(cycle)+ qo;
    cum_wat(cycle) = cum_wat(cycle) + qw;
    end

    if time <= injTime(cycle) 
    Tavg = Ts;
    end

    WOR = qw/qo;
    OSR = cum_oil_tot/cum_steam_tot;

cumTime = cumTime + 1.0;
 time = time + timeStep;
end
end




**Error:**

 - Error in GetSteamZoneParameters (line 7)  tcD = FindtcD( fhv );   

   Output argument "angleOfInclination" (and maybe others) not assigned
   during call to
   "H:\MATLAB\CSI-mine\GetSteamZoneParameters.m>GetSteamZoneParameters".

   Error in SAGD (line 29) [Qi, angleOfInclination, steamZoneRadius,
   steamZoneVolume ] = GetSteamZoneParameters( Qi,fhv, tD, cycle, rinj,
   Xinj, time, injTime, Tavg, Ti, Mr, Ts, reservoirThickness, length1);




function [Qi, angleOfInclination, steamZoneRadius, steamZoneVolume ] = GetSteamZoneParameters( Qi,fhv, tD, cycle, rinj, Xinj, time,... 
                                                                                               injTime, Tavg, Ti, Mr, Ts, reservoirThickness, length1)
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here


 tcD = FindtcD( fhv );   
 Ehs = GetEhs( tD, tcD );
 wt = 5.615*rinj(cycle)*62.4; 
 ws = Xinj*wt;

if( time ~= 0.0 && time <= injTime(cycle)) 
Qi = Qi+(wt*(h_wat(Tavg)-h_wat(Ti))+ws*latent_heat_vapor(Tavg));

end

if (time <= injTime(cycle))
steamZoneVolume = Ehs*Qi(cycle)/(Mr*(Ts-Ti));
steamZoneArea = steamZoneVolume/reservoirThickness;
steamZoneRadius = steamZoneArea / length1;
angleOfInclination =(180.0/pi)*atan(steamZoneRadius/reservoirThickness);
end
end
```

Comment: fhv = 0.8606 @Robert GetVolumetricHeatCapacities returns all its output arguments. I did it the way you said 'writing fhv in between the two lines'. The Error remains the same. I think there is some error in 'GetSteamZoneParameters'. Even when I remove 'tcD = FindtcD( fhv )' I get an error for the next line ' Ehs = GetEhs( tD, tcD );' and it continues.

Comment: Is `FindtcD` a MEX function? It looks like the error is coming from inside that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, **read** the error message:

```
"angleOfInclination" was not assigned
```

That means, `GetSteamZoneParameters` did not set this variable and then of course throws an error when it should return.
Which, looking at this function, means that the following if-condition is obviously not true:

```
if (time <= injTime(cycle))
    ..
end
```

So you should probably define and alternative value to the variables from within the if block in an else block.